# Why is this the Helmholtz Free Energy for the Onsager Ising Model?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

I'm reading through Kerson Huang's presentation of the Onsager solution. We end up determining that the natural log of the partition function is

$$\ln Z = \frac{1}{2}\ln (\frac{2 \cosh^2(2 \beta \epsilon)}{\sinh (2 \beta \epsilon)}) + \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\phi \ln \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2 \sin^2 \phi})$$

with $\epsilon$ and $\phi$ being determined from the bond interactions. Now, I understand that the Helmholtz free energy takes the formula $F = -\frac{1}{\beta} \ln Z$. Given this formula, I don't understand how the book then goes on to say that the Helmholtz free energy is

$$\beta F = -\ln(2\cosh(2 \beta \epsilon)) - \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\phi \ln \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2 \sin^2 \phi}).$$

I believe there was a mathematical error made in equating $\frac{1}{2}\ln (\frac{2 \cosh^2(2 \beta \epsilon)}{\sinh (2 \beta \epsilon)})$ and $-\ln(2\cosh(2 \beta \epsilon))$ but I'm not entirely sure and am hoping somebody could elucidate what exactly is going on here. Thank you!

Comment: Use the identities for cosh, sinh, $cosh^2$ etc. and a little bit of algebra (assuming there is no error) and you should get the same result.

Comment: @Drjh No, it is obvious that the first expression is singular at $\epsilon=0$, while the latter isn't. Therefore, there is no way they can coincide. However, it is not an error in the book, but a confusion on the OP's part (see my answer).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Where is your answer? Link?

Comment: @Drjh Right below. :) The point is that the first quantity given by the OP is *not* what he thinks it is. It is related to the free energy through a nontrivial identity given in the book and from which the second identity follows immediately.

Comment: I must get a another copy of Huang's book. I remember we used it year 4 and it was a fantastic book! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call $Z$ and Huang calls $\Lambda$ is not the partition function. It is related to the latter through equation (15.61) in the book. Using the latter equation and the formula you state for $\Lambda$ ($Z$ in your notation), you immediately obtain the result Huang states for $\beta F$.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I took a look at expression (15.61) again and did the math and got the correct answer. Thank you!